# How do I check if a user has been created?

Tags: terminal

How do I demonstrate that these users have been created and are assigned to their a certain group?

Can I do this by the command line or do I have to do it by the GUI (graphical user interface)

Comment: What is "these users"? Please clarify. Are you just looking for a way to check existence and group membership of users (like the `groups` command)?

Answer (score 2):

To prove a user exists, use `getent passwd <userid>`. If it shows you a user record, that user exists. Possibly remotely (i.e. LDAP), not necessarily locally (`/etc/passwd`). To list a users groups, use `groups <userid>`.